Legitimate uses of “antisemitic”
See this comment.
It not just calls some users here antisemitic, it calls the ICC itself antisemitic!
I suggest that such language should be proscribed.
More generally, as I've said before, IMHO hot topics
should be off topic... for entirely pragmatic reasons: after all if this stack tries to settle the Israel-Palestine conflict:

It's not very likely to succeed
A general slugfest will inevitably follow
Other more germane (to philosophy) discussions will slink away onto the backburner...
... at best. Or else just disappear

Which is why I suggest that we carefully stay away from unmanageable questions/issues.

PS. I thought of flagging the whole thread for deletion. But then thought to first ask re. policy
PPS. I deleted my politics-SE account for similar reasons — it had become physically nauseating

"antisemites support the ICC (and upvote this answer)" - that sounds like a weasel worded association fallacy - it's not technically calling the ICC antisemitic, but it's suggesting that it is, or at least that it's bad (one might say "racists support imprisoning Steve Madeupname" to suggest we shouldn't do that, but that's independent of good reasons to imprison him, e.g. he's a serial killer). But calling other users antisemitic (for merely upvoting) I'd say is well past the line of rudeness.

Rude comments should be flagged. It's up to you whether you flag additional comments as "no longer needed" / conversational because they are conversational or because they would no longer make sense if the rude comment they're replying to is deleted. I don't think you have to worry too much about where precisely the line of rudeness is - if a comment seems rude, it's probably not all that appropriate as a comment in any case, and there are too many such comments to reflect in depth on each individually. If you flag it and your flag gets declined, maybe then it's worth asking the question.

@NotThatGuy As I said to Causative below, we have different valuations. If I call you an a__hole, you can do likewise, we can glower at each other for a while and move on. But if accusations are made of the sort SE seniors directed at Monica Celio, it can be more seriously consequential in terms of friends, jobs, residence. IOW rudeness is not really a big deal (at least in my scheme of things). This goes more toward slander/libel etc though ofc IANAL

"If I call you an a__hole, you can do likewise" - but neither of those would be appropriate for the comments. You'd also really have to reach to conclude some analogy of the former is happening from people merely upvoting an answer which contains zero antisemitic rhetoric (one would have to assume those people also consider the ICC to be antisemitic, which many simply don't - it's the common societal problem of people ascribing malice to anyone who disagrees with them). "This goes more toward slander/libel" - maybe, maybe not, but flagging it as rude is still the recommended course of action.

@IgorF. I didn't see that comment (and it's deleted now), but I'd probably say that's less rude (but still a bit rude). Still not appropriate for comments, but the comments were moved to chat and chat is far less strict about what's allowed there than comments (whether that's reasonable or not, it is the case that they're less strict).

@NotThatGuy So in your opinion, a (general) hater is not as bad as a Jew-hater? Is there a metric by which we can measure the badness of words?

@NotThatGuy I don't personally believe that chat is less strict than comments is meaningful policy; still less in the cases where multiple paries carry a lot of opposing anger. I once again reiterate my position: When it's a question of a current hot war, it's best to proscribe the entire topic (on phil-SE — politics-SE is another matter, that's why I deleted my account there)

So for example, a serious ethics question on Who is right between Israel and Palestine given xyz context, abc actions etc would be a v valid philosophy/ethics question. But in practice it would derail completely

@Rushi Comments are more strict because it doesn't (formally) allow discussion. Anything that even vaguely approaches the realm of arguably impolite (beyond some blunt facts and corrections) may very well be too conversational and thus subject to deletion. (Also, far fewer people pay attention to chat, at least in smaller rooms, so it's easier for things to slip through the cracks, and it seems to be moderated by regular users to a large degree.)

The (now deleted) comment read:

The fact that antisemites support the ICC (and upvote this answer), especially after Oct.7, is enough reason to consider it a travesty of justice.

Describing the ICC as "antisemitic" is a matter of political opinion. People are allowed to hold views we don't agree with. If an authority cited in an answer as a moral arbitrator did happen to be corrupt in some way, saying so could be a relevant comment. Although I don't really think a lengthy argument about contemporary politics qualifies as philosophy.
However, the comment also makes a personal attack against people who upvoted the answer, and personal attacks have no place here.

I understand and respect this opinion. But I don't agree. If there are no stable points of reference in our discourse how does the discourse proceed or even start? But I say I understand because I'm v cognizant of the default western mores that obtain out here — individualism

+1 --- Since all Comments are deleted eventually, I guess people can post potentially not acceptable things (not stuff we would all say is obviously off-limits) and wait for the radioactive decay timer to expire. More dangerous gets flagged sooner, right? Also: I like the "politics is not philosophy" message, but I wish that politics included more philosophy. They have mastered the Ad Hominem part...

And - I'guess you're not going to like it - this behaviour perfectly fits the well-known "It Began When the Jews Fought Back" (https://www.frontpagemag.com/it-began-when-the-jews-fought-back-video/)

@IgorF. Personal attacks are not compatible with rational discussion. Since you pointed it out I deleted that comment as well. Anyway Philip moved the whole comment thread to chat two days ago (indeed lengthy arguments about contemporary politics are not philosophy).

I cannot imagine any circumstance where characterizing someone as anything in a comment would ever be related to the proper purposes of comments.

I dont understand... We do have conversations in comments don't  we? [They may and perhaps shuld be shortlived conversations — thats a different topic] Youre not allowed to say to me Hey Rushi! Dont be silly! ? (1) I would defend your right to do that (and me to respond!) (2) More pertinently I never VTC because I want to have options like Cut the crap! and its not on the menu.  In short I dont like the idea of artificial sanitization of speech. But once again: I really dont understand what you mean to say...

You can omit the qualification of silliness and get straight to the point (explaining what is wrong with the silly thing Rushi wrote).

While I dont specifically disagree with the answers and comments I am seeing, I am surprised by the lack of nuance.
What I see is like trying to paint a fine painting with a coarse brush.
As a more extended analogy I will take a universal bugbear of the modern world
Racism
Now many things can and have been called racism.
Ive tried to make an increasing list of instances:

What cute curly hair you have!
Where are you really from?
I won’t sit next to you Rosa Parks, on the bus.
They — the Polish — take our — British — jobs!
Non brahmin caste may not drink water from this well
Coinciding with Dogs and Indians not allowed
The gypsies are not like us. They don’t fit in.
I don’t want my kids going to school with that filth from inner Johannesburg.
There's no such thing as an xyz people
Recent
Older
Also cruel spoofs

    8a. Of course it's on both sides
           Drive them into the sea!

For us (Hutus) those people (Tutsis) are cockroaches.

Genocide the whole continent of  untermenschen
Usually euphemized to things like
Endlösung der Judenfrage
Lebensraum im Osten


Analysis
Now while the list above may not be in perfectly increasing order, overall I hope people will generally agree that n+1 is worse than n.
Now if we call 1. »racism« and if we call 10.  »also racism« clearly there is something so woefully inadequate about our categories that it makes meaningful discourse senseless.

Racism is a "prejudice, discrimination, or antagonism against a person or people on the basis of their membership of a particular racial or ethnic group". Anything that meets that definition... meets that definition. There are degrees of racism. The real world is filled with spectrums, not cleanly separable categories - spectrums are often better described by adding adjectives, e.g. "slightly cold", "very cold", "slightly racist" or "very racist". Just because something isn't genocide doesn't make it "not racism". We also indicate genocide is worse by calling it "genocide".

Although the issue here is the commenter in question was basically calling *others* racist, but it's questionable if the behaviour of those people even gets as far as #2 on your list, and also, such accusations are not appropriate for the comments.

@NotThatGuy Sure everything you say is fine. I'm just wondering... »rude«?? Is that whats wrong? Was Sara Chipps' problem that she was 'rude' to Monica Celio?

@ Rushi Maybe. "Rude" is a rather broad categorisation. There may be more fitting descriptions that are more specific to any given scenario, e.g. slander. But we don't have a separate flag for that, and we probably shouldn't have one, because we'll just confuse users if they have to classify rudeness into one of a bunch of different categories (I already almost never use the more serious rude flag, but then again, more egregious rudeness is rare).

@ScottRowe  Its done regularly. Perhaps more relevant

@IgorF. Yes this kind of discussion should not — according to me — happen on main. It needs to happen on meta so that there's some clarity what must not pass muster on main. (This is meta; not main — do remember!)

You commented also on the main, as I point out in my answer.
